# React mui get firestore data in card view

Tags: reactjs, firebase, material-ui

I have a cardview from Material UI (MUI) react

```
  <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia 
           component="img" 
           height="140" 
           image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg" 
           alt="green iguana"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
   </Card>
```

I am trying to populate the data in Firestore into this card view can someone help me do this

Comment: Reading data from Firestore is quite well documented, so I recommend starting here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data. If you get stuck on a specific step making that work in your app, edit your question to include a [minimal repro of that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.